# Howto execute a sql command inside transaction

Tags: orientdb

I am using OrientDb Version 2.0 M2 with PLocal connections.

The javadoc of 
`OCommandRequest com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.command(OCommandRequest iCommand)`
says
"Executes commands against the graph. Commands are executed outside transaction."

Now i am wondering, if it is possible to execute my SQL commands inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

With current version it's not possible if you use "remote" connections.

Comment: i use PLocal connections. Is it possible?

Comment: so I suppose this should work also if you embed the server, right?

Comment: @Lvca You said with current version two years ago. Is this still an accurate statement? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765065/how-to-use-transactions-on-remote-orientdb